# Android: Going back to previous activity and pass it an array

Tags: android, android-activity

I have the activity A and the activity B
The activity A opens activity B with a Button and I passed it an array
In the activity B I modify the array and when I click on a button I want to return or open the activity A again and pass it the modified array

Is there a way to do that?

Sorry for my English

In this case I have BeginService class and I pass the array to another activity in `new ConceptsActivity(bill.getService());` The ConceptsActivity modify the array and pass it to BeginService again and so on. I do this because I need to add services to my bill.
Here's the code for BeginService class

```
public class BeginService extends AppCompatActivity {
private Service service[] = new Service[5];

Bill bill = new Bill();

public BeginService(){

}

public BeginService(Service service[]){
    this.service = service;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTitle(R.string.TitleSer);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_concepts);
}

public void openConcepts(View view){
    new ConceptsActivity(bill.getService());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ConceptsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

ConceptsActivity class

```
public class ConceptsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private int i=0;
private AutoCompleteTextView actv;
private TextView tvConcept;
private TextView tvConcept2;
private TextView warning;
private TextView tvPrice;
private TextView tvbs;
private EditText price;
private Button addConcept;
private String concept;
private double priceDo;
private List<AddConceptsListView> myConcept = new ArrayList<AddConceptsListView>();

private Service[] service; //= new Service[5];

public ConceptsActivity(){

}

public ConceptsActivity(Service service[]){
    this.service = service;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTitle(R.string.TitleSer);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.concepts_layout);


    for(int j=0; j<service.length; j++){
        service[j] = new Service();
        if(service[j].getName() != null){
            i++;
        }
    }

    actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextViewConcept);
    tvConcept = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewConcept);
    tvConcept2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewConcept2);
    warning = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewWarning);
    tvPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
    price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPrice);
    addConcept = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddConcept);

    //Autocomplete Textview
    String[] services = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.services_array);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, services);
    actv.setAdapter(adapter);

    actv.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                //make items visible
                tvConcept.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvConcept2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                addConcept.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                concept = actv.getText()+"";
                tvConcept2.setText(concept);
                //To hide the keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
}

public void onClickAddConcept(View view){
    if(price.getText().toString().equals("")){
        warning.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        warning.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        priceDo = Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Precio: " + priceDo+ "" + "\n"
                + "Concepto: " + concept,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        service[i].setName(concept);
        service[i].setPrice(priceDo);
        i++;

        for(int j=0; j<service.length; j++){
            if(service[j].getName() != null || service[j].getPrice() != null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Array" + j + "nameConcept: " + service[j].getName() +
                        "\n" + "Array price: " + service[j].getPrice(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    ArrayAdapter<Service> my = new ArrayAdapter<Service>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, service);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_concepts);
    tvbs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBeginService);
    tvbs.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ListView mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
    mainListView.setAdapter(my);

}
```

Comment: Look at startActivityForResult/onActicityResult and bundles

Comment: Have you considered using Bundle's

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34737301/3498931 .. you can do it using Intent .. i gave short example there.. check it out..

Comment: Thanks I wonder if is there a way to pass an array that is custom type : e.g  Service [] service 
In a bundle?

Answer (score 1):

Use `setResult` in your target Activity:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent .putExtra("arrayName", your_array_name);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

In your first activity, add

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      switch(requestCode) {
        case (MY_CHILD_ACTIVITY) : {
          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
           ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arrayName");
              // myList gives you the array list
          }
          break;
        } 
      }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't use the ArrayList, I need an array of an object type